# TYPO3 - Accessing detail page of record via url GET parameter

Tags: typo3, realurl, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I developed an extbase extension with list and detail view (list and show action). Without using realurl ... the link of a detail view looks like this:

```
domain/index.php?id=43&/?tx_abc_abc[record]=1&tx_abc_abc[action]=show&tx_abc_abc[controller]=Abc
```

And when I change the record id in the url I can dynamically change the content on the detail page and access the record:

```
domain/index.php?id=43&/?tx_abc_abc[record]=2&tx_abc_abc[action]=show&tx_abc_abc[controller]=Abc 
domain/index.php?id=43&/?tx_abc_abc[record]=3&tx_abc_abc[action]=show&tx_abc_abc[controller]=Abc 
domain/index.php?id=43&/?tx_abc_abc[record]=4&tx_abc_abc[action]=show&tx_abc_abc[controller]=Abc
```

The final goal is having a url looking like this and access the record via the GET parameter in the url:

```
domain/abc/?abc=1
domain/abc/?abc=2
domain/abc/?abc=3
domain/abc/?abc=4
```

But when activating realurl ... I cannot directly access the record if its not available in tx_realurl_urldata. Or how should the realurl setup look like?

What's the best solution for this? I have too many records (plus 2 languages) for the links to be written and always available in tx_realurl_urldata.

So my thought was to deactivate realurl for this specific extension? But how?

Or I thought to exclude the detail page in realurl_conf.php: 'excludePageIds' => 42,43  but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I made a realurl configuration for my own extension for detail pages like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = [
    'www.domain.ch' => [
        ...
        ],
        'fixedPostVars' => [
            'extYourextensionDetailConfiguration' => [
                [
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_yourextension_abc[action]',
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ],
                [
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_yourtextension_abc[abc]',
                    'lookUpTable' => [
                        'table' => 'tx_yourextension_domain_model_abc',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND deleted=0 AND hidden=0',
                        'useUniqueCache' => true,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => [
                            'strtolower' => true,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                        ],
                        'enable404forInvalidAlias' => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            ...,
            '99' => 'extYourextensionDetailConfiguration',
            ...,
        ],
        ...,
    ],
];
```

Where

- www.domain.ch is your domain
- extYourextensionDetailConfiguration is a name to use later
- alias_field is the content of the segment. can be ID if you want to switch between changing the URL handmade
- 99 is the ID of the page with the detail view

Comment: That's the setup I also have an it works. Yet it only works if a specific path is already available in tx_realurl_urldata. This means for 1 million records and 2 languages ... 3 million speaking_url paths need to be available in tx_realurl_urldata. When is a record available in tx_realurl_urldata? -> ... if I output the specific record e.g. via list action. But if a record hasn't been queried ... it is not available in tx_realurl_urldata and the link doesn't work. Yet if I deactivate realurl ... I can easily change any record uid in the url as described above and get the record information ...

Comment: I understand what you wrote. But how should detail pages accessed when records are not listed?

Comment: That's what I'm not sure as well. At the end I would like to have sth like: https://www.wienerborse.at/marktdaten/aktien-sonstige/preisdaten/?ID_NOTATION=6217489&ISIN=AT0000603709 ... e.g. do you think sth like https://usetypo3.com/json-view.html is capable of providing this?